Optimizing Python Code faster that 4 seconds
I have written some code to solve an online problem, Here.
mustConstraint = set()
notConstraint = set()
violated = 0
satisfied = 0 

for i in range(0, int(input(''))):
    constraint = input('')
    mustConstraint.add(frozenset(constraint.split()))

for i in range(0, int(input(''))):
    constraint = input('')
    notConstraint.add(frozenset(constraint.split()))

for i in range(0, int(input(''))):
    group = input('')
    group = set(group.split())

    for x in mustConstraint:
        if x & group == x:
            satisfied +=1
        
    for y in notConstraint:
        if y & group == y:
            violated += 1

violated += len(mustConstraint) - satisfied

print(violated)

To summarize the problem, the first line of input contains a positive integer X, with X => 0. the following X lines of input will contain two words, separated by whitespace. These two words must be in the same group. the next line of input will contain another positive integer Y, with Y => 0. the next Y lines of input will contain two words, separated by whitespace. these two words must not be in the same group. the next line of input will contain a positive integer, G with G >= 1. The next G lines of input will each consist of three different words, separated by single spaces. These three words have been placed in the same group.
Output an integer between 0 and X+Y which is the number of constraints that are violated.
I highly recommend you visit the problem site here, since the problem is much easier to understand with the sample cases provided and their explanations.
Unfortunately, since the last batch has ~300,000 inputs, my nested for loops are far to slow, and fail to meet the 4 second time limit - Can someone help me optimize my code?

Most of the delay comes from this block:
for i in range(0, int(input(''))):
    group = input('')
    group = set(group.split())

    for x in mustConstraint:
        if x & group == x:
            satisfied +=1
        
    for y in notConstraint:
        if y & group == y:
            violated += 1

the nested for loops perform 100,000^2 iteration each, amounting to a total 20 billion iterations form that code block (2*100,000^2)
if someone could find a way to reduce the number of iterations, it would make a substantial difference.

Please describe what the code is doing here, not just with a link to an external site. And the results should be posted as text, not screenshots.

I don't understand what all the int(input(''))s are doing - are you using those as a placeholder for something else? please explain fully.

@Vin The first line of input is the number of rows of names. So for i in range(0, int(input(''))): reads the number of lines, then reads that many lines.

I am not doing competition programming, but I would say that the solution for a lot of inputs is about algorithm design rather than implementation. You could have written your code in ASM, I think your solution is too naive; this is the source of the performance issue.

The most obvious optimization is to change x & group == x to x.issubset(y). issubset() can use short-circuiting so it won't be as slow for large sets.

I see you accepted answers here and in your previous question. Please don't forget to still fix both questions as requested in their comments (in this case @Barmar's first comment). Remember that questions and answers here are supposed to be useful for everybody, including future visitors with the same / similar problems. (Really I shouldn't have answered here yet before you fixed it, I just was too tired to notice it myself and I read the comments only afterwards.)

@nocomment Fixed, thanks for your feedback!

Thanks. Although as you said yourself: "the problem is much easier to understand with the sample cases provided and their explanations". So better include a sample case + explanation. I'd actually make up my own, as I don't like the site's. Like, put Batman and Robin in the musts, and Batman and Joker in the must-nots. Much better than the site's meaningless names.

Two solutions, both easily pass all tests.
Solution 1: Minimal change
Replace your large inner loops with the tiny loop over the group's three pairs, i.e., change
    for x in mustConstraint:
        if x & group == x:
            satisfied +=1
        
    for y in notConstraint:
        if y & group == y:
            violated += 1

to this:
    a, b, c = group
    for pair in {a, b}, {a, c}, {b, c}:
        if pair in mustConstraint:
            satisfied += 1
        if pair in notConstraint:
            violated += 1

Solution 2: Just two set operations
All three sections specify a set of pairs. Helps to put that into a function. Then find/count the violations:

Pairs that must be but aren't.
Pairs that must not be but are.

from itertools import combinations

def pairs():
    return {
        frozenset(pair)
        for _ in range(int(input()))
        for pair in combinations(input().split(), 2)
    }

must = pairs()
must_not = pairs()
are = pairs()

print(len(must - are) + len(must_not & are))


You can utilize set operations more efficiently:
Read all input at once for efficiency.
Use dictionaries to store constraints and sets to represent groups.
Efficiently check constraints by iterating through each group and updating the violation count.
Like this:
import sys

input = sys.stdin.read
data = input().splitlines()

index = 0

# Read must constraints
must_constraint_count = int(data[index])
index += 1
must_constraints = []
for _ in range(must_constraint_count):
    must_constraints.append(set(data[index].split()))
    index += 1

# Read not constraints
not_constraint_count = int(data[index])
index += 1
not_constraints = []
for _ in range(not_constraint_count):
    not_constraints.append(set(data[index].split()))
    index += 1

# Read groups
group_count = int(data[index])
index += 1
groups = []
for _ in range(group_count):
    groups.append(set(data[index].split()))
    index += 1

# Check constraints
satisfied = 0
violated = 0

# Check must constraints
for must in must_constraints:
    in_same_group = False
    for group in groups:
        if must.issubset(group):
            satisfied += 1
            in_same_group = True
            break
    if not in_same_group:
        violated += 1

# Check not constraints
for not_c in not_constraints:
    for group in groups:
        if not_c.issubset(group):
            violated += 1
            break

print(violated)

Input Handling: The entire input is read at once using sys.stdin.read for efficiency.
Storing Constraints: Constraints are stored in lists of sets for easy checking.
Processing groups: groups are stored as sets to leverage the fast subset checks.
Checking constraints:
For each must constraint, check if the constraint set is a subset of any group. If it is, it's satisfied. If not, it's violated.
For each not constraint, check if the constraint set is a subset of any group. If it is, it's violated.
Performance:
The use of sets and the issubset() method makes the constraint checking efficient.
Reading all input at once and processing it in-memory avoids multiple I/O operations, which speeds up execution.
You can find more help with complex common operations at Big-O Cheat Sheet.
Also, Python's Time Complexity explains very well the performance characteristics of Python's builtin datatypes.

"This reduces the number of iterations" - Does it? How so? - "and improves the performance significantly" - Does it? How much?

Answer to both my questions, as far as I can tell: No it doesn't. Submitted at the site, it fails at the first large test case just like the OP's code. As expected.

The answer is great, and their are clear improvements, but it still doesn't meet the 4 second time constraint. Thank you for your feedback!

Thanks for the feedback!
The edits were a key to figure it out, thanks for your help; there was no merge button to press, I'm new to this UI, I edited the original.

Still about as highly inefficient as before, and still fails the first large test case.
